# How can I tell if an intent is a service/activity/broadcast?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there someway I can get details of what type of intent I'm dealing with from the intent object? I'm handed an intent and I have to choose to startActivity, startService etc. with the intent.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. An Intent cannot be a Service/Activity. And about what to do with it, you don't provide enough context. Starting an Activity or a Service is your choice providing the behavior requested by the Intent. More context would be helpful for your question.

Comment: @m0skit0, when I create the intent, I point the intent to the Activity/Service right? `new Intent(context, activity/service class)` Based on that, I'd like to figure out if I need to run it as an activity or as a Service

Comment: I donot understand your question. In android it is the caller who decides if he want to to start an activiy, a service or send a broadcast. It is the job of the android-os to find out, which Activity/service/broadcastReceiver matches the intent. Is your question "how to find out, if an intent matches a certain Activity/service/broadcastReceiver?"

Answer (score 0):

The API should be changed to hand you a `PendingIntent`, which handles this problem. Or, the API should be changed to hand you a flag (e.g., some enum) that indicates what you are supposed to do with the `Intent`.

You are certainly welcome to use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`, `queryIntentServices()`, and `queryBroadcastReceivers()` to try to deduce what you are supposed to do with the `Intent`, but I worry about performance.